# Is it possible to import a "data points graph" widget from a file into dashboard?

Tags: csv, cumulocity

I'm using Cumulocity dashboards to visually analyze measurement data from sensor nodes, using "data points graph" widgets.
Manually creating the widgets is a tedious and time consuming job. Is it possible to create a CSV (or similar) file for creating widgets in a dashboard? That would really help and save a lot of time. I know there is a similar feature for bulk creation of devices.

Comment: Once you create a dashboard, you can copy and paste it around. Click on the cog at top-right.

Comment: If you create a dashboard on a device, you can also choose to show that dashboard for all devices of the same type.